# Git: remove some commits from a branch

Tags: git, git-squash

Let's say I have, in a given working branch, a history of commits that looks like the below:

```
commithash1 [task-a] lorem ipsum
commithash2 [task-a] dolor sit amet
commithash3 [task-b] consectetur adipiscing
commithash4 [task-c] elit se do
commithash5 [task-a] eiusmod tempor
```

It's like that because someone merged this working branch with the contents of Develop branch and inserted some new commits after that.

The idea is to keep on it only the commits labeled as  "[task-a]", that is, commit hashes 1, 2, and 5 only, removing the other ones. I need to group them, so I can squash these commits and rebase from develop right after.

Is that doable? If so, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: You can do this with interactive rebase `git rebase -i HEAD^5`

Comment: But be careful: if this branch is shared with others (i.e. it has already been pushed and pulled by others), you must not rebase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an answer(ish) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73167269/git-remove-some-commits-from-a-branch#comment129221629_73167269) (at least right now) but it has a typo in it.  [Matt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73167269/git-remove-some-commits-from-a-branch#comment129223087_73167269) has a useful warning as well: it's generally unwise to rebase commits that someone else is using.

Note, too, that if the parent of commit-hash-5 is commit-hash-4, what you'll end up with is a *new and improved* commit with commit-hash-6, whose parent is commit-hash-2. The old commit-hash-5 commit continues to exist.  Your pseudo-`git log --oneline` output is missing key `--graph` data so I cannot be sure what's going on here.  But we can say some things generally about this.

In particular, a *branch name* simply hold the *raw hash ID* of some commit.  Whatever hash ID is stored *in* the branch name, we call that the *tip commit* of the branch.  The output from `git log --oneline` is normally shown in reverse: that is, rather than:

```
commithash1 [task-a] lorem ipsum
commithash2 [task-a] dolor sit amet
commithash3 [task-b] consectetur adipiscing
commithash4 [task-c] elit se do
commithash5 [task-a] eiusmod tempor
```

we'd see:

```
commit5 (branchname) [task-a] eiusmod tempor
commit4 [task-c] elit se do
commit3 [task-b] consectetur adipiscing
commit2 [task-a] dolor sit amet
commit1 [task-a] lorem ipsum
```

(and with `--graph` we'd see if there are any branch-and-merge sequences in there as well).  Running `git rebase -i HEAD~5` (not `HEAD^5`, which is the typo) would bring up a rebase command sheet with `pick` commands for each of the commit hashes, and in the *edit sheet* they're shown in normal-human-person order, i.e., forwards, rather than in backwards Git order.  But Git actually *finds* them backwards: rebase has to fix that, and `git log` *doesn't* have to fix that and normally doesn't bother.

What I like to do here is *draw the commits*, using single uppercase letters to stand in for each commit.  There's some commit "before" hash #1; let's call that commit `B`, and assign letters `C-D-E-F-G` to the remaining five commits and draw those in, like this:

```
...--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- branchname
```

We say that the *name* `branchname` *points to* commit `G`, here.  Commit `G` stores a full snapshot of all files, plus some metadata, and the metadata *in* commit `G` stores the hash ID of earlier commit `F`.  So we say that commit `G` *points to* commit `F`.  Commit `F`, being a commit, also stores a snapshot and metadata, and its stored hash ID is that of earlier commit `E`, i.e., `[task-b] consectetur adipiscing`.  Of course commit `E` is a commit, so it points backwards to commit `D`, and so on.

There are two more constraints we have here:

- A branch name can only point to *one* commit.  We can pick any commit, or make any new commits that we like, but we only get to point it to *one* commit.
- No commit can ever change.  (Not even `git commit --amend` actually *changes* a commit: it fakes it; the `--amend` is a lie, albeit a useful lie.)

Since commits `C-D` are fine as is, we can leave them alone.  The problem starts at commit `E`, and becomes significant at commit `G`, because `G` points backwards to `F`, and that's the intolerable error.

To fix that error, we must copy `G` to a new and improved `G'`.  There will be two key differences between commit `G` and the new-and-improved `G'`:

- `G'`'s parent will be `D`, not `F`;
- `G'`'s snapshot will be `D`'s plus whatever *change* happened *between* `F` and `G`.

To achieve this, we'll essentially *check out* commit `D` and run `git cherry-pick` to copy `G`, giving:

```
...--B--C--D--E--F--G
            \
             G'
```

as the overall set of *commits* in the repository.  This leaves us with two more problems:

- We now have to make the name `branchname` point to `G'`.  We can do this with `git branch -f` (if we're not "on" the branch at the time) or `git reset --hard` (if we are "on" the branch at the time).
- When we move `branchname`, we'll lose the ability to *find* commit `G`, unless we save its hash ID somewhere.  As long as commit `G` is "trash" or "junk" or "rubbish" or whatever, to be swept up and disposed of later, that's fine.  But commit `G` is how we find commit `F` aka `[task-c] elit se do`.  So we need to create *some* name to *remember* the hash ID of `F`.

The way to do that is:

- create a new name now, to remember `F`; then
- use `git rebase` (with or without `-i`) to create `G'` and move `branchname`.

One sequence of commands to do this is, assuming we're on branch `branchname` right now:

```
git branch save-them HEAD~1      # create save-them to remember F
git rebase --onto HEAD~3 HEAD~1  # copy G to G'
```

The `--onto` argument's value `HEAD~3` tells `git rebase` *where to put the copy*.  The `HEAD~1` argument tells `git rebase` what *not* to copy: i.e., copy commit `G`, but not commit `F` or anything earlier.  (Rebase copies the commits that are *not* reachable from its non-`--onto` argument, but *are* reachable from `HEAD`, so that's what `git log HEAD~1..HEAD` would show, which is commit `G` if we're on branch `branchname` when we start all this.)

We can draw the final result this way:

```
                   G   [abandoned]
                  /
...--B--C--D--E--F   <-- save-them
            \
             G'  <-- branchname (HEAD)
```

Note that commit `G` still *exists*.  It's just that we've *forgotten how to find it*.  We won't see it in `git log` output.  If that particular commit exists in any *other* clone, it still exists in that other clone, and that could be a problem later, but if we're the only Git repository in the entire universe that holds commit `G`, the fact that *we* have (deliberately) forgotten how to find it means *nobody* will find it any more.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, I learned a lot from it.